# what is the dependency for sdk version 19

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sanity_softwares.smsaccesspermission"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
```

Comment: What do you mean ? . also can you add full build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

v4 is the best support library for sdk 19. 
In v7 material design was introduced which supports a lot of features that require 21.